# Adding sound to a basic Java quiz game

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to figure out the best way to add some music to a basic quiz game I've created in Java. Was wondering if anybody had any opinions on what would be best...? I've got some of the basics down on adding sound, but just can't figure this one out. I just don't know where to put the code for the audio file.

Here is my game:

Quiz.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;

//Create the main quiz and its elements
class Quiz extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel panel;
    JPanel panelresult;
    JRadioButton choice1;
    JRadioButton choice2;
    JRadioButton choice3;
    JRadioButton choice4;
    ButtonGroup bg;
    JLabel lblmess;
    JButton btnext;

    // These arrays will hold the strings of the questions and the answers.
    String[][] questionsAnswers;
    String[][] correctAnswer;

    // This will be the key in the HashMap.
    int qaid;

    // Using a HashMap to output my data.
    HashMap<Integer, String> map;

    // Setting up the game board.
    Quiz() {
        initializedata();
        setTitle("Music Quiz");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1100, 600);
        setLocation(300, 100);
        setResizable(false);
        Container cont = getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(null);
        cont.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        bg = new ButtonGroup();
        choice1 = new JRadioButton("Choice1", true);
        choice2 = new JRadioButton("Choice2", false);
        choice3 = new JRadioButton("Choice3", false);
        choice4 = new JRadioButton("Choice4", false);
        bg.add(choice1);
        bg.add(choice2);
        bg.add(choice3);
        bg.add(choice4);

        lblmess = new JLabel("Choose a correct anwswer");
        lblmess.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        lblmess.setFont(new Font("Berlin Sans FB", Font.ITALIC, 23));

        btnext = new JButton("Next");
        btnext.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        btnext.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 35));
        btnext.addActionListener(this);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        panel.setLocation(10, 10);
        panel.setSize(1100, 550);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2));
        panel.add(lblmess);
        panel.add(choice1);
        panel.add(choice2);
        panel.add(choice3);
        panel.add(choice4);
        panel.add(btnext);
        cont.add(panel);
        setVisible(true);

        // Set the inital HashMap key to 0
        qaid = 0;

        // Call the readqa method with a starting point of 0
        readqa(qaid);

    }

    // Method for determining what buttons are being selected.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (btnext.getText().equals("Next")) {
            if (qaid < 9) {

                map.put(qaid, getSelection());
                qaid++;
                readqa(qaid);
            } else {
                map.put(qaid, getSelection());
                btnext.setText("Show answers");

            }
        } else if (btnext.getText().equals("Show answers"))
            new Report();

    }

    public void initializedata() {
        // questionsAnswers stores pairs of questions and its possible answers
        questionsAnswers = new String[10][5];

        questionsAnswers[0][0] = "1) Which singer was in MadMax:BeyondTheThunderdome?";
        questionsAnswers[0][1] = "David Bowie";
        questionsAnswers[0][2] = "Tina Turner";
        questionsAnswers[0][3] = "Mick Fleetwood";
        questionsAnswers[0][4] = "James Brown";

        questionsAnswers[1][0] = "2) Which reggae singing star died 11th May 1981?";
        questionsAnswers[1][1] = "Peter Tosh";
        questionsAnswers[1][2] = "Jimmy Cliff";
        questionsAnswers[1][3] = "Bob Marley";
        questionsAnswers[1][4] = "Gregory Isaacs";

        questionsAnswers[2][0] = "3) Who was The Beatles first drummer?";
        questionsAnswers[2][1] = "Richard Starks";
        questionsAnswers[2][2] = "Ringo Starr";
        questionsAnswers[2][3] = "Peter Gunn";
        questionsAnswers[2][4] = "Peter Best";

        questionsAnswers[3][0] = "4) What is Bruce Springsteen's nickname?";
        questionsAnswers[3][1] = "The Boss";
        questionsAnswers[3][2] = "The Big Man";
        questionsAnswers[3][3] = "The Killer";
        questionsAnswers[3][4] = "The Ice Man";

        questionsAnswers[4][0] = "5) Led Zeppelin rose from the ashes of what group?";
        questionsAnswers[4][1] = "The Byrds";
        questionsAnswers[4][2] = "The Yardbirds";
        questionsAnswers[4][3] = "The Animals";
        questionsAnswers[4][4] = "The Pretty Things";

        questionsAnswers[5][0] = "6) Which Beatle is pictured first walking across the road on the Abbey Road album cover?";
        questionsAnswers[5][1] = "John";
        questionsAnswers[5][2] = "Paul";
        questionsAnswers[5][3] = "George";
        questionsAnswers[5][4] = "Ringo";

        questionsAnswers[6][0] = "7) In 1987, I Still Haven’t Found What I’m Looking For was U2's first number one hit in which country?";
        questionsAnswers[6][1] = "Ireland";
        questionsAnswers[6][2] = "Canada";
        questionsAnswers[6][3] = "U.S.A.";
        questionsAnswers[6][4] = "Great Britain";

        questionsAnswers[7][0] = "8) Which Jimi Hendrix classic contained the line ‘Scuse me while I kiss the sky?";
        questionsAnswers[7][1] = "Hey Joe";
        questionsAnswers[7][2] = "Wind Cries Mary";
        questionsAnswers[7][3] = "Fire";
        questionsAnswers[7][4] = "Purple Haze";

        questionsAnswers[8][0] = "9) What show did MTV introduce in 1987 to feature heavy metal music and news?";
        questionsAnswers[8][1] = "Headbangers Ball";
        questionsAnswers[8][2] = "Rock N Heavy";
        questionsAnswers[8][3] = "Night Tracks";
        questionsAnswers[8][4] = "Metal Mayhem";

        questionsAnswers[9][0] = "10) What Miami rap group created controversy with their album “As Nasty As They Wanna Be”?";
        questionsAnswers[9][1] = "N.W.A.";
        questionsAnswers[9][2] = "Run DMC";
        questionsAnswers[9][3] = "2 Live Crew";
        questionsAnswers[9][4] = "Digital Underground";

        // correctAnswer stores pairs of question and its correct answer
        correctAnswer = new String[10][2];

        correctAnswer[0][0] = "Which singer was in Mad Max: Beyond The Thunderdome?";
        correctAnswer[0][1] = "Tina Turner";

        correctAnswer[1][0] = "Which reggae singing star died 11th May 1981?";
        correctAnswer[1][1] = "Bob Marley";

        correctAnswer[2][0] = "Who was The Beatles first drummer?";
        correctAnswer[2][1] = "Peter Best";

        correctAnswer[3][0] = "What is Bruce Springsteen's nickname?";
        correctAnswer[3][1] = "The Boss";

        correctAnswer[4][0] = "Led Zeppelin rose from the ashes of what group?";
        correctAnswer[4][1] = "The Yardbirds";

        correctAnswer[5][0] = "Which Beatle is pictured first walking across the road on the Abbey Road album cover?";
        correctAnswer[5][1] = "John";

        correctAnswer[6][0] = "In 1987, I Still Haven’t Found What I’m Looking For was U2's first number one hit in which country?";
        correctAnswer[6][1] = "U.S.A.";

        correctAnswer[7][0] = "Which Jimi Hendrix classic contained the line 'Scuse me while I kiss the sky?";
        correctAnswer[7][1] = "Purple Haze";

        correctAnswer[8][0] = "What show did MTV introduce in 1987 to feature heavy metal music and news?";
        correctAnswer[8][1] = "Headbangers Ball";

        correctAnswer[9][0] = "What Miami rap group created controversy with their album “As Nasty As They Wanna Be”?";
        correctAnswer[9][1] = "2 Live Crew";

        // Create a map object to store pairs of questions and the selected
        // answer
        map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    }

    // This will get the user selection and store it for later use
    public String getSelection() {
        String selectedChoice = null;
        Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons = bg.getElements();
        while (buttons.hasMoreElements()) {
            JRadioButton temp = (JRadioButton) buttons.nextElement();
            if (temp.isSelected()) {
                selectedChoice = temp.getText();
            }
        }
        return (selectedChoice);
    }

    public void readqa(int qid) {
        lblmess.setText("  " + questionsAnswers[qid][0]);
        choice1.setText(questionsAnswers[qid][1]);
        choice2.setText(questionsAnswers[qid][2]);
        choice3.setText(questionsAnswers[qid][3]);
        choice4.setText(questionsAnswers[qid][4]);
        choice1.setSelected(true);
    }

    public void reset() {
        qaid = 0;
        map.clear();
        readqa(qaid);
        btnext.setText("Next");
    }

    public int calCorrectAnswer() {
        int qnum = 10;
        int count = 0;
        for (int qid = 0; qid < qnum; qid++)
            if (correctAnswer[qid][1].equals(map.get(qid)))
                count++;
        return count;
    }

    public class Report extends JFrame {
        Report() {
            setTitle("Answers");
            setSize(1450, 550);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    dispose();
                    reset();
                }
            });
            Draw d = new Draw();
            add(d);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        class Draw extends Canvas {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                int qnum = 10;
                int x = 10;
                int y = 20;
                for (int i = 0; i < qnum; i++) {
                    // Print the 1st column
                    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                    g.drawString(i + 1 + ". " + correctAnswer[i][0], x, y);
                    y += 30;
                    g.setFont(new Font("Candara", Font.PLAIN, 22));
                    g.drawString("      Correct answer:" + correctAnswer[i][1],
                            x, y);
                    y += 30;
                    g.drawString("      Your answer:" + map.get(i), x, y);
                    y += 30;
                    // Print the 2nd column
                    if (y > 400) {
                        y = 20;
                        x = 550;
                    }

                }
                // Show number of correct answers
                int numc = calCorrectAnswer();
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                g.drawString("Number of correct answers:" + numc, 300, 500);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

QuizProgram.java

```
public class QuizProgram {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Quiz();

    }

}
```

Comment: Format your code like a normal person please .-.

Comment: *"I've got some of the basics down on adding sound,.."* Where in that 290 LOC did you try anything sound related?  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example) that actually shows your attempt to use this knowledge. 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)